# What does && mean in npm and what is it called?

Tags: bash

For example:

```
$ npm i && cd client && npm i && cd ..
```

Newbie question, I know.

Comment: This has nothing to do with npm, this is for the shell.

Answer (score 0):

This is for the shell itself for concatenation of conditions, please use this [Npm Guide](https://medium.com/javascript-training/introduction-to-using-npm-as-a-build-tool-b41076f488b0)  as a reference as it will clear alot of questions you have and is a very helpful tool all together.

Comment: >implying I will actually do that